# how does netflix calculate the percentage match scores?

Tags: recommender-system, similarity

I know that these scores are calculated by considering the users' past interactions. But I need some details here. For example, suppose that user A has watched the movies X, Y, and Z. For a new movie M, we can find the similarities of the pairs (X,M), (Y,M), and (Z,M). Then we can take an average to find the similarity (match) between user A and movie M. However, the similarity scores will not be nicely distributed between 0 and 1. In most of the time the values will be very small but being small does not imply that this has a low match. In other words, match percentage and similarity scores are not well aligned. There should be some kind of alignment and that is what I'm asking.

Comment: The recommender system netflix uses is not public. However, I am pretty sure it does not calculate only the similarities between movies (seen and unseen) but it create users' profiles in a sort of embeddings and calculates a similarity score between user and movies